# Is there a way to get text within tags with specific attributes with bs4?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Say I have this in a HTML file:

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="result__a" href="some_link">Foo-baz</a>
```

How do I extract just `Foo-baz` using bs4?

Right now, I'm able to get the `href` attribute with

```py
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
}

page = requests.get('the_url', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser').find_all("a", class_="result__a")

for link in soup:
    print(link['href'])
```

However, I'm not able to extract the words within that particular tag with those specific attributes.
I've tried different solutions from both the documentation, and StackOverflow right here, but they don't seem to work. Or maybe I'm not able to execute it since I'm new to bs4.

The link is: https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us the url of the page?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web scraping duckduckgo, but getting the links in the wrong format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578946/web-scraping-duckduckgo-but-getting-the-links-in-the-wrong-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `link['href']` use `link.text`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
}

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("a", class_="result__a")

for link in soup:
    print(link.text)
```

Prints:

```
Test | Definition of Test by Merriam-Webster
Speedtest by Ookla - The Global Broadband Speed Test
Internet Speed Test | Fast.com
Tests.com Practice Tests
Speed test
Testing for COVID-19 | CDC
Xfinity Speed Test - Check Your Internet Speed
Internet Speed Test - AT&T Official Site
Speed Test by Speedcheck - Test your internet speed
Mic Test
Test - definition of test by The Free Dictionary
CPS Test - Check Clicks per Second
Free Personality Test | 16Personalities
CEA Test: MedlinePlus Medical Test
Test Innovators | Prep for Success
Join a Test Meeting - Zoom
TEST Synonyms: 83 Synonyms & Antonyms for TEST | Thesaurus.com
Speakeasy Internet Speed Test - Check Your Broadband Speed ...
Speed Test - Telstra
IQTest.com--The Original Free Online IQ Test
Speedtest by Ookla - Teste de Velocidade de Conexão da ...
Speedtest - Google Search
ADHD Test - Psych Central
Cisco Webex | Test online meeting
Login | Salesforce
Practice Tests, Tutoring & Prep Courses | Kaplan Test Prep
test | Origin and meaning of test by Online Etymology ...
Test English - Prepare for your English exam
Internet Speed Test - Check Your Internet Speed | Cox
A1C test - Mayo Clinic
```

Comment: Ohh, `link.text`. It returns all text from a webpage, if I'm not wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors.

If you want to scrape javascript version of DuckDuckGo, you can use `request-html` or `selenium`. *Note: it's not the fastest solutions.*

You can do it by parsing data from the `<script>` tags, but it would require more work.

Code (non-javascript):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test&kl=us-en', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select('.result__body'):
  title = result.select_one('.result__a').text
  url = result.select_one('.result__snippet')['href'].replace('//', '')
  snippet = result.select_one('.result__snippet').text
  print(f"{title}\n{url}\n{snippet}\n")

-----
'''
Test | Definition of Test by Merriam-Webster
duckduckgo.com/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.merriam%2Dwebster.com%2Fdictionary%2Ftest&rut=4749db61adf540ccd15b6f5aa6a68d4e6604b2c86e5bffe0a5380e06513eff93
Test definition is - a means of testing: such as. How to use test in a sentence.
...
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [DuckDuckGo Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/duckduckgo-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that here you're parsing a non-javascript DuckDuckGo page (*see this [URL](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=test&kl=us-en&ia=web), and you'll "recent news", "inline images" results*) while SerpApi is parsing the javascript version of the page. And the only thing that really needs to be done is to iterate over JSON string and get the data you want.

Code to integrate:

```py
import json, os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
  "engine": "duckduckgo",
  "q": "fus ro dah",
  "kl": "us-en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
    print(json.dumps(result, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

------------
'''
{
  "position": 1,
  "title": "Test | Definition of Test by Merriam-Webster",
  "link": "https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test",
  "snippet": "Test definition is - a means of testing: such as. How to use test in a sentence.",
  "favicon": "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/ip3/www.merriam-webster.com.ico"
}
...
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.